# How to set a timeout for a bufio scanner that scans in a loop?

Tags: go, io, goroutine

I am using golang to start a process and monitor the output. The process will run for a long time, and I need to be able to send a signal to end it.

I have the following code which works well in most time. However, the process may have no output for some reason, and the for loop would be blocked by `Scan()` method and failed to receive from `processFinishChan`.

Is there a easy way to set a timeout for `Scan()` method? I tried a solution that run `Scan()` in another goroutine, and use another select to receive from the new goroutine and a timeout channel, but considering the outer `for` loop, would there be more and more goroutines that blocked by `Scan`?

```
// code that start the process...
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

for {
    select {
    case <-processFinishChan: // send to this channel to terminate the process
        log.Println("Killing Process")
        err := cmdObject.Process.Kill()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error Killing: %v", err)
        } else {
            return
        }
    default:
        // default case, read the output of process and send to user.
        if !scanner.Scan() && scanner.Err() == nil {
            // reach EOF
            return
        }
        m := scanner.Bytes()

        WSOutChanHolder.mu.Lock()
        for _, ch := range WSOutChanHolder.data {
            ch <- m
        }
        WSOutChanHolder.mu.Unlock()
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `time.After()` inside the select, and go routine to scan

Comment: @mooga I tried that, but the `Scan` method is still there and the goroutine won't end, there would be more and more dead goroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `stdout` is the result of `cmdObject.StdoutPipe()`, the reader should close the reader and interrupt any ongoing reads when waiting after the process exits.

> Wait will close the pipe after seeing the command exit, so most callers need not close the pipe themselves.

So, we need to kill the process in a separate goroutine, then `Wait` after killing the process to observe it happen and close the reader.

```golang
// code that start the process...
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

go func() {
    <-processFinishChan: // send to this channel to terminate the process
    log.Println("Killing Process")
    err := cmdObject.Process.Kill()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error Killing: %v", err)
    } 

    cmdObject.Wait()
} ()

for {
    // default case, read the output of process and send to user.
    if !scanner.Scan() && scanner.Err() == nil {
        // reach EOF
        return
    }
    m := scanner.Bytes()

    WSOutChanHolder.mu.Lock()
    for _, ch := range WSOutChanHolder.data {
        ch <- m
    }
    WSOutChanHolder.mu.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. By the way, I saw your answer about `SetReadDeadline`, and I didn't find an equivalent for `io.ReadCloser` or `io.Reader`, so is there a way to achieve something like "read for 3 seconds, if read nothing, continue the next line"?

Comment: I thought at first that the `stdout` var was from `os.Stdout`, but realized later that it was from a sub process. The `ReadCloser` returned is the read end of a `io.Pipe` which doesn't have such facilities. The writer end of the pipe is installed in `cmd.Stdout` https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd. You could always implement a custom writer / pipe which would allow you to set a context, but that is slightly more work.